# Didn't show merchant ID and merchant key in paytm in test mode?

Tags: javascript, react-native, payment, paytm

I want to integrate paytm in react native app.

i create merchant id and key in test mode, and i also get success popup that it created but its doesn't show anywhere.

[image]

please help me how and where to get generated test API keys

Comment: please contact paytm development support

Answer (score 1):

I mailed paytm they told me try this on **incognito mode**.
i tried that and it worked.

Comment: It can be a comment to question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried in incognito also but it did not work when I wrote an mail about these issues along with screenshots, I came to know they are not onboarding any new customers for now (due to some licence-related issue from their end)

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue, the website would not display the test API keys, on mailing the paytm dev support team, this is what i got:

> Hi,  Greetings from Paytm.
>
> Many thanks for your interest in initiating a new relationship with
> Paytm for Payment Aggregator Solutions.
>
> Pursuant to our internal compliance decision, we deeply regret to
> inform you that at this stage, we shall not be able to go ahead with
> the opening of a new relationship for Payment Aggregator solution.
>
> We are taking all the necessary steps to resubmit our Payment
> Aggregator license application. We are quite hopeful to have it done
> soon. We will keep you apprised of the developments.
>
> We apologize for the inconvenience caused and sincerely look forward
> to connecting with you in the near future, to partner with you and
> have you onboard.
>
> Kindly bear with us until then.

Response recieved from Paytm on March 12th 2024.

Answer (score -2):

Please log out once from your dashboard and then log in again, if the issue still persists please raise a query on Paytm developer Support