# Unable to get PAYTM test API keys

Tags: paytm

I wanted to integrate Paytm api in my project to make secure payments on my MERN stack website. But test api keys are not getting generated on paytm website.

I tried opening site in incognito mode as well. Is there any solution for this? Or shall I go with another payment gateway aggregator?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Didn't show merchant ID and merchant key in paytm in test mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68962914/didnt-show-merchant-id-and-merchant-key-in-paytm-in-test-mode)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a business account for test keys, have a look at [official documentation](https://business.paytm.com/blog/how-to-generate-api-key-for-payment-gateway-integration-new-merchants/).

I would recommend you to use Stripe as integrating it is simple and they have a lot of examples for it too.